# Given X a set with 100 real numbers and sum 0. Proof that the sum of at least 99 pairs from X is non negative.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, pigeonhole-principle

I see that this problem this problem has something to do with Pigeonhole principal, but I can't see how to proof it.

The other part of the question asks if this result of how many pairs is the best estimative we can do and why.

Comment: If $15$ of the numbers are positive, there will be $105$ pairs of them and the statement is satisfied.  If there is a problem, there must be rather few positive numbers.  Then they must be larger in magnitude generally than the negative ones.

Comment: The set $\{-1,-1,-1,\cdots,-1,-1,99\}$ provides an example where no more than $99$ pairs are non-negative.